# Maximum Modulus Principle used on boundaries of domains in \Bbb C

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D$ be a domain in $\Bbb C$, and $u$ be the real part of a function $f$ which is analytic on $D$. Assume $u$ is constant on the boundary of $D$. Show that $f$ is constant on $D$.

Well, I know that if $u$ is constant on the boundary, the by CR $f$ also is. Further, $|f|$ achieves it's max on the boundary, thus the constant value is it's max. From here I am unsure about where to go.

Comment: Just a thought: Assuming $D$ is the open unit ball (say, by Riemann mapping), then by Mean-Value, $u(0)$ is that constant value. Hence, $g = e^f$ attains its max at $0 \in D$. Hence by Maximum Modulus, $g$ has to be constant. Thus $f$ has to be constant?

Comment: I have not learned the mean value theorem for complex functions nor the Riemann mapping theorem, nor would I have to know them for the comprehensive final this question came from.

Comment: No No. I meant the mean-value theorem for real-valued harmonic functions. ie. the fact that $u(0)$ would be equal to the average of $u$ on the unit circle.

Comment: What about $f(z)=z$, where $D$ is the half-plane defined by $Re(z)>0$? In this case, $u$ is identically zero on the boundary line. I think, you are missing some assumptions in your question.